# How to create window(CreateWindowEx) which support transparency and hosted by WPF window?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, sdl-2

I'm trying to create window which support transparency, and put it in WPF window in .net4.5

I decide use : `HwndHost`, so I extend `HwndHost` class and override the `BuildWindowCore` method in it:

```
protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
{
    _winHand = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, "static", string.Empty, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, _width, _height, hwndParent.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    // set it support transparent
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_windowHandle, 100, 0, 2);
 
    return new HandleRef(this, _winHand);
}
```

But at the end It will throw exception: **Hosted HWND must be a child window of the specified parent.**

Now I'm in the dead loop, If I want a transparency window, it must be `WS_POPUP` style, but if I want to put the window in wpf by `HwndHost`, it must be `WS_Child`

Is there anyway to make it?

The reason The window must be the transparency window, because I need to use **SDL2** render some rgba image which include alpha channel. but if I did not set, the window can't show the alpha channel as transparency.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? WPF supports transparency already. Also why do you need to create the window yourself, why can't you just call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` after the window is created?

Comment: @Charlieface, WPF support transparency, but I need to create a window for `SDL2` for render the image(or more complex stuf), `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` would return `false` if the style not `WS_POPUP`

Comment: If by "Transparency Window", you mean a windows with the WS_EX_LAYERED style, it does not need to be a popup.  It can be a child Window.  At least since WIndows version 8.  You don't have to write code for a version older than that, do you?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles